# Como aplicar/buscar transformações global/local em OpenGL

Tags: c++, matriz, lua, opengl, engine

Estou programando uma simples Game Engine utilizando a API gráfica **OpenGL**. Mas estou com um problema que não consigo resolver. O problema é que as transformações no *world* (mundo) não funcionam corretamente. As transformações de escala estão normais, mas a de translação e rotação que são o problema.

Por exemplo, se eu mover a câmera localmente e depois rotacionar o mesmo globalmente no eixo Y (eixo que aponta para cima) e localmente no eixo X (um simples mouse look), a câmera começa a rotacionar como um pivô tendo o seu centro de origem onde ela foi criada.

Cada objeto/entidade na Engine tem uma classe base `HTransform`, que serve para rotacionar/mover/escalonar global/local (local, ao longo do seu próprio eixo).
 E possuí uma função para atualizar a matriz de transformação. Depois de feito as transformações eu aplico a matriz `m_WorldTransform`. Na matriz da câmera eu utilizo o `glLoadMatrixf`, e nos objetos `glMultMatrixf`.

```
// C++ - Resumo da classe HTransform

void setWorldPosition(const HVec3f& pos);
Hvec3f getWorldPosition() const;
// Ect......

HVec3f m_WorldPosition;
HQuaternion m_WorldOrientation;
HVec3f m_WorldScaling;

HVec3f m_LocalPosition;
HQuaternion m_LocalOrientation;
HVec3f m_LocalScaling;

HMatrix4 m_WorldTransform;
HMatrix4 m_LocalTransform;

void HTransform::updateTransform()
{
    m_WorldTransform.setRotationAxis(m_WorldOrientation.getAngle(), m_WorldOrientation.getAxis());
    m_WorldTransform.translate(m_WorldPosition);
    m_WorldTransform.scale(m_WorldScaling);

    m_LocalTransform.setRotationAxis(m_LocalOrientation.getAngle(), m_LocalOrientation.getAxis());
    m_LocalTransform.translate(m_LocalPosition);
    m_LocalTransform.scale(m_LocalScaling);

    m_WorldTransform = m_WorldTransform * m_LocalTransform;// * m_WorldTransform.getInverse();

    m_NeedTransformUpdate = false;
}
```

A câmera também possuí a classe base `HTransform`.

```
// C++ - Resumo da classe HCamera
HMatrix4 m_MatView;
HMatrix4 m_MatProjection;

void HeCamera::updateViewMatrix()
{
    //this->updateTransform();

    m_WorldTransform.setRotationAxis(m_WorldOrientation.getAngle(), m_WorldOrientation.getAxis());
    m_WorldTransform.translate(m_WorldPosition);
    m_WorldTransform.scale(m_WorldScaling);

    m_LocalTransform.setRotationAxis(m_LocalOrientation.getAngle(), m_LocalOrientation.getAxis());
    m_LocalTransform.translate(m_LocalPosition);
    m_LocalTransform.scale(m_LocalScaling);

    m_WorldTransform = m_WorldTransform * m_LocalTransform;

    m_MatView = m_WorldTransform.invert();
    m_NeedTransformUpdate = false;
}
```

Como podem perceber cada object/entidade ira usar duas matrizes, uma para transformações global e outra para transformações locais. Mas queria utilizar a penas uma, mas não sei como fazer.

Fiz o **[upload de um demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fsqpq1dwarkj3r/Engine%20Test.rar)** para visualizar melhor o problema. Os controles são W, A, S, D, Q e E para os movimentos e o mouse para controlar a orientação da câmera (um MouseLook).

O demo contem um arquivo `script_test.lua` que a partir da linha 75, está a parte que controla a orientação/rotação da câmera.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2):

À primeira vista, existe uma particularidade na ordem em que você está aplicando duas transformações:

> m_WorldTransform.translate(m_WorldPosition);
>
> m_WorldTransform.scale(m_WorldScaling);

Se você mover primeiro, e redimensionar depois, a translação acabará sendo afetada pelo redimensionamento. Por exemplo, se você mover +10 no eixo X, e depois redimensionar o eixo X por 0,5, você terá, efetivamente, reduzido o tamanho do objeto em X para metade, e movido apenas +5 na direção do eixo X.

Isso porque todas as transformações tomam como base a origem do espaço (0, 0, 0). O mesmo ocorre com a rotação, e todas as outras transformações lineares.

Se quiser testar essas transformações, e tiver um browser que suporte WebGL, você pode utilizar um material interativo online que eu disponibilizo a meus alunos da faculdade: [WebGL - Matrizes e Transformações LinearesInício](http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/WebGL/Matrix.html).

Faça o seguinte teste:

Crie uma translação (10, 0, 0), depois adicione um redimensionamento (50%, 100% 100%). Selecione o último item da lista e clique em "Animar passo a passo". Em seguida, inverta a ordem da translação e do redimensionamento, selecione o último item da lista e clique em "Animar passo a passo".

Com isso você pode sentir a diferença visualmente.

Comment: Legal o material do link. Bem útil mesmo.

Comment: Valeu! Se encontrar algum bug, pode me avisar ;)

Comment: Entendi, mas se eu fizer isso os objetos não vão sofrer a transformação ao longo do seu próprio eixo (local). Pode notar que no demo que postei, logo quando é aberto o objeto (um cubo) já aparece rotacionado 45º no seu eixo global `Y` e com uma escala de 3 no seu eixo local `X` (Eu fiz o teste). Esta na linha 28 e 29 do script que acompanha o demo.

Comment: A diferença entre local e global, é apenas que tudo que for local, matematicamente é aplicado antes do que for global. Executando o código, acho que entendi melhor sua pergunta. Você gostaria que a câmera não andasse apenas ao longo dos eixos X, Y e Z, mas que andasse na direção em que a câmera está "olhando", certo? Como se fosse uma pessoa passeando em um parque, entendi certo?

Comment: Exatamente, mas não só a câmera, para qualquer objeto/entidade que utilize a classe `HTransform` (que é a classe responsável transformações). Ela possui os métodos `setWorldOrientation` e `setLocalOrientation`, que são para transformações globais/locais. Mas venho pesquisando isso já a um bom tempo e não encontro uma resposta :/. Mas você olhou o demo só para entender melhor o que esta acontecendo?

Comment: É porque esse "orientation" é apenas outra forma de dizer "matriz de rotação". Para que o objeto/câmera se mova na direção que ele está "olhando", você precisa manualmente aplicar a rotação do ângulo da sua orientação aos parâmetros utilizados como delta do movimento. Por exemplo, supondo que o objeto possua uma rotação de $ no eixo Y, então, na hora de mover você não deve pedir para que ele se mova `(dx, dy, dz)`, mas sim `(dx * cos($), dy, dz * sin($))` (pode precisar mudar para -sin e/ou -cos, dependendo do seu sistema de coordenadas).